# Redis Cluster fail-over issue. Slave to master promotion takes more than 2 seconds. How to solve it?

Tags: redis

**I have a Redis cluster with multiple masters and 1 slave per master.
I am using jedis. Redis version is : 3.0.7.
Now when one of the master goes down Jedis is trying to make slave as master and it takes more than 2 seconds. Which is a huge time in the my scenarios.**

*Following the two different Exceptions and the Stack :
JedisClusterException & JedisClusterMaxRedirectionsException.

```
JedisConnectionException!! - exc: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisClusterException: CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisClusterException: CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:115)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:222)
at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.incr(Jedis.java:548)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster$27.execute(JedisCluster.java:319)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster$27.execute(JedisCluster.java:316)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:119)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.run(JedisClusterCommand.java:30)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.incr(JedisCluster.java:321)
at com.demo.redisCluster.App.main(App.java:37)
.................................................
JedisClusterMaxRedirectionsException!! - exc: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisClusterMaxRedirectionsException: Too many Cluster redirections?
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisClusterMaxRedirectionsException: Too many Cluster redirections?
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:97)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:131)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:152)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:131)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:152)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:131)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.run(JedisClusterCommand.java:30)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.incr(JedisCluster.java:321)
at com.demo.redisCluster.App.main(App.java:37)*
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on the failure scenario? What is the cause of the failure?

Comment: While load testing we did this by killing the master server process. The exception stack is when  we try to add some key value in redis while redis slave is not promoted to master. and after about 2 sec it will start working.  The issue is 2 secs of time is a huge issue for us.

Comment: 2 secs is not too much time for a failover process. Think about it. When a server suddenly goes down, there is something checking the healthy of that server, and only after it realizes the server is down, it promotes the slave. Actually, 2 secs is very quick. Maybe you just need to catch this exception, sleep for about 5~10 seconds and try again.